# My Motor is really slow on Arduino

Tags: unity-game-engine, arduino

```
int motorPin1 = 8;
int motorPin2 = 9;
int motorPin3 = 10;
int motorPin4 = 11;
int delayTime = 2;
char myCol[20];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  pinMode(motorPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorPin3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorPin4, OUTPUT);
}


void loop() {
  int lf = 1;
  Serial.readBytesUntil(lf, myCol, 1);
  if (strcmp(myCol, "p") == 0)
  {
    Play();
  }
  if (strcmp(myCol, "s") == 0)
  {
    Stop();
  }
}



void Play()
{
  digitalWrite(motorPin1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin4, LOW);
  delay(delayTime);
  digitalWrite(motorPin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin4, LOW);
  delay(delayTime);
  digitalWrite(motorPin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin4, HIGH);
  delay(delayTime);
  digitalWrite(motorPin1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin4, HIGH);
  delay(delayTime);
}

void Stop()
{
  digitalWrite(motorPin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin4, LOW);
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.IO.Ports;
    using System.Threading;

    public class Sending : MonoBehaviour {

    //public static SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None, 8,       StopBits.One);
    public static SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);

    void Start () {
        OpenConnection();
    }



    public void OpenConnection() 
    {
       if (sp != null) 
       {
         if (sp.IsOpen) 
         {
          sp.Close();
            }
        else 
         {
          sp.Open();   
         }
       }
    }

    void OnApplicationQuit() 
    {
       sp.Close();
    }

    public static void play(){
        sp.Write("p");
    }


    public static void stop(){
        sp.Write("s");
    }
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class Play : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnMouseDown() {
        Sending.play();
     }

}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class Stop : MonoBehaviour {


    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Sending.stop();
    }

}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

Hi, i have this code in my arduino and unity, i command it from unity with a play and stop button, but when i press my play button , the motor run but reaaaaally slowly like a step, 1/2 second then another step ..... Can someone please help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking a guess here...

The first thing loop() does is call "Serial.readBytesUntil(...)" before getting a chance to call your Play() routine to make the motor take a step. If there are no characters to read from the serial connections, it will timeout... eventually.

Maybe try Serial.setTimeout(1) (or even try a 0?) for a shorter timeout -- just to see if that helps the situation.  (Don't use it as a solution.)

I would think about separating the command processing from the motor stepping.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Delay function takes it's argument in milliseconds, so you are running your motors for 2 milliseconds at a time. Try 2000 instead. Below is a reference to the delay() function.

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Delay

If it still doesn't work consider following:

Digital pins of Arduino typically output only around 20mA (Arduino Uno R3). For motors this is often not enough and you will need a motor shield externally powered from batteries or a DC supply, like the one below;

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoMotorShieldR3

However if you run motors, especially several, directly for Arduino you can expect them to run slowly or barely run at all.

Comment: i know how Delay works, if i put 2000 , my motor will take 8 seconds for 1 step, it'll be even slower

Comment: If you are using usual hobby electric motor putting voltage across it for a longer time will definitely not make it slower. 

For further help your full hardware setup is needed.

Comment: Check the digital output pins with multimeter - they should go high and low accordingly.

Also, if you have a shield you would typically not use the digital output pins but the specially designed connections on the shield. There is probably an appropriate library for the shield, in that case use the included functions instead for digitalWrite.